# Is the HTTP Keep-Alive timeout refreshed by new requests?

Tags: http, timeout, keep-alive

I found two types of explanations online and on SO about the `Keep-Alive: timeout=N` directive in a server response's headers:

1. The `timeout` value indicates the maximum duration that the underlying TCP connection should **live**, i.e. new requests using the connection **do not refresh this timeout**.
2. The `timeout` value indicates the maximum duration that the underlying TCP connection should **stay idle** for, i.e. new requests using the connection **do refresh the timeout to its initial value**.

Which of these two is true? Do all HTTP client implementations respect the same spec for this?

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer to this? I am experiencing an issue and think its related